# Cannot find protocol declaration for 'MapViewControllerDelegate'; did you mean 'UIPageViewControllerDelegate'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

I have an App has written in objective C and I uploaded a new version of it before 2 months and everything was working perfectly, now I want to add some things but I get this error: Cannot find protocol declaration for `MapViewControllerDelegate`; did you mean `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol MapViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)closeViewController;

@end

@interface RoomServiceViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak,nonatomic) id <MapViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Cannot find protocol declaration for `MapViewControllerDelegate`; did you mean `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`?

Replace `MapViewControllerDelegate` with `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`

Reference to `MapViewControllerDelegate` is ambiguous

Comment: Can you add your viewcontroller redirection code so we can get idea.

Comment: Do you mean to the .m file?

Comment: From where redirected 'RoomServiceViewController' this viewcontroller? That code I want to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged UIPageViewController and XCode is your type confusing with UIPageViewControllerDelegate: Do you have an UIPageViewController somewhere that is also referring to your protocol?

If yes:
Objective-C types aren't automatically known in your project. You need to include their header files. Else you get funny best guesses.

Another option. Move the protocol to a separate headerfile and see if this clears thing up.

Also if you used include instead of import you end up with odd compiler errors.

Comment: I didn't understand why I get these errors everything was ok, the difference is just my new computer, the problem is with the MapViewControllerDelegate protocol and I have problem with all the .h files that this protocol is inside of them

Comment: How about moving the Protocol to a separate Headerfile? Are you using #import or #include?

Comment: No chance to tell without the project. The Controller gets displayed and dismissed. How about a breakpoint on the dismiss func within the controller. Checking where the dismiss comes from.

Comment: I took the protocol and declare it in a new header file, and then I delete the protocol declaration from the other files and its worked for me, thank you!